# Send Authorization Header on each Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Our project consists of an MVC area which handles authentication/authorization and rendering of pages, and an API area which also requires authentication/authorization and sends data to the page. We decided to go stateless for the server, so each request must include the authorization header with the user's credentials.

I accomplish this with the API calls with `xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authCookie);` in jquery's `beforeSend`, however I am unsure how to do this for the MVC side (each time you click a link or enter a URL, the request should include the Authorization header). Currently I'm doing this inside `Application_BeginRequest` and setting `Request.Headers["Authorization"] = Request.Cookies["auth"];`, but I want the Authorization header to be in the initial request, and not just tacked on after the request has been sent.

Comment: [I've removed the tags from your title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/when-should-we-remove-pseudo-tags-from-a-title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you won't be able to set Headers; when the browser directs you to a link via an anchor click (unless you catch all anchor clicks using jquery, seems like overkill), nor will headers be sent on Form submits (Get/Post, unless you again catch all forms submissions), and the killer is the fact that [server side redirects will also not resend any custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026050/mvc-redirect-with-custom-headers).

Instead of answering how to do something in jQuery, I would highly recommend reconsidering your design because based on the above facts, you will most likely run into technical limitations.

Comment: Just to clarify, the jQuery is used for attaching the auth header before sending ajax calls to the API and is not used for navigating pages. If I can't persist the Authorization header for all requests, is grabbing the credentials from the request cookies the best way to send credentials on every request? This is what I did initially, but I thought since there's a header specifically for Authorization, I should try use that.

Comment: Are you using the WebAPI?

Comment: Well my solution is separated into an API project and an MVC project (may not be best, but I thought there would be conflicts with controllers if I had them in the same project). It's the MVC project that I have difficulties with for the Authorization header, since for the API I only ever call using ajax, so I can explicitly set the Authorization header before sending the request.

Comment: Controllers don't have to conflict if you use the namespaces parameters in [MapRoute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460158(v=vs.108).aspx).  Regardless, you can also [share cookies across different ASP.Net products overiding the domain for cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7592668/209259).  So unless you are using Windows Auth (not recommended), there isn't any reason both sites can't share authentication with simple web.config change.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for all the info. One final question: could you provide more information on the "simple web.config change"? Duplication of my authentication/authorization is probably my biggest concern with splitting these into separate projects. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the link on my previous comment with all the instructions.

Comment: Sorry I down voted your answer, it is only a miss click. and I can not remove it.